# instance var was not kept across the method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is code in customers controller:

```
  def edit
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
    @return_to = params[:return_to]     
  end

  def update
    @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])

    if @customer.update_attributes(params[:customer], :as => :roles_new_update)

    redirect_to @return_to, :notice => 'Customer was updated successfaully!'
    else
      render 'edit', :notice => 'Customer was not updated!'
    end
  end
```

It is verified that there is value in @return_to in method edit. However there is an error saying: Cannot redirect to nil! for

```
   redirect_to @return_to, :notice => 'Customer was updated successfaully!'
```

in method update.

Any thoughts about the error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you are on the edit action, that is one request to show the form. Then when you submit the form, that is a second request calling the update action. Any states set in an action are confined to that action alone. There's a few ways to use data across multiple actions:

1. The database (So save it in a model)
2. The session hash
3. Pass it in the view to go into your form.

Because it's a redirect/return to value, i would suggestion using a session variable such as:

```
session[:return_to] = params[:return_to]
```

In your edit action, then just refer to that value in your update:

```
session[:return_to]
```

Comment: You are right about using session to keep the value which was initially implemented and worked. The reason for introducing @return_to is that I haven't figured out how to rspec test redirect_to session[:return_to].    Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand; `edit` doesn't call `update`, so there'd be no intrinsic reason for `@return_to` to still exist.

Are you aware that controllers are created per-request?